# Set ENV variables for Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, configuration, yaml

I've followed the steps from [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mZ_gverN4Co) video from railscasts for setting `ENV` variables.

This is my configuration:

**config/database.yml**

```xml
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  username: <%= ENV['DATABASE_USERNAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

development:
  <<: *default
database: <%= ENV['DATABASE_NAME'] %>
test:
  <<: *default
database: <%= ENV['DATABASE_NAME'] %>
production:
  <<: *default
  database: <%= ENV['DATABASE_NAME'] %>
  username: <%= ENV['DATABASE_USERNAME'] %>
password: <%= ENV['DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

**config/application.rb**

```rb
config = YAML.load(File.read(File.expand_path('../application.yml', __FILE__)))
config.merge! config.fetch(Rails.env, {})
config.each do |key, value|
    ENV[key] = value.to_s unless value.kind_of? Hash
end
```

**config/application.yml**

```xml
development:

  DATABASE_USERNAME: "username goes here"
  DATABASE_PASSWORD: "password goes here"
  DATABASE_NAME: "database name goes here"

  SECRET_KEY_BASE: "secret key goes here"

test:

  DATABASE_USERNAME: "username goes here"
  DATABASE_PASSWORD: "password goes here"
  DATABASE_NAME: "database name goes here"

  SECRET_KEY_BASE: "secret key goes here"

production:

  DATABASE_USERNAME: "username goes here"
  DATABASE_PASSWORD: "password goes here"
  DATABASE_NAME: "database name goes here"

  SECRET_KEY_BASE: "secret key goes here"
```

Does this configuration follow best practices, or need some changes?

Comment: Best Practice would be to have ENV Variables from shell. `VAR=value rails server`.

Comment: What if you have different credentials for username and password or database_name configuration ?

Comment: What're you thinking? Production/Development?

Comment: (in case of setting ENV Variables from shell) what if you have more than one app? I guess the username and password would be the same but the database_name could be different on each case, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for what you use `config/application.yml` instead use `config/secrets.yml`. It is already implemented in Rails. Than you can fetch your key by:

```
Rails.application.secrets
```

even more, add to `config/application.rb` variable `SECRETS = Rails.application.secrets` and now you can use it:

```
SECRETS[:my_secret_key]
```

read more [IN RAILS DOCS](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/4_1_release_notes.html#config-secrets-yml)

Comment: so, everything I have in `config/application.yml` should move to `config/secrets.yml`, right? so the ENV variables should be in another .yml file likw I have or in shell ?

Comment: yes, move data from `application.yml` to `secret.yml`. ENV variables you need in HEROKU, AWS etc, but for example in DigitalOcean or in local server you can work with `secrets.yml`

Answer (score 1):

An Alternative is ..

Add gem 'config' to your Gemfile and run bundle install to install it. Then run

```
rails g config:install
```

which will generate customizable config file config/initializers/config.rb and set of default settings files:

```
config/settings.yml
config/settings/development.yml
config/settings/production.yml
config/settings/test.yml
```

You can now edit them to adjust to your needs. a

see the usage in https://github.com/railsconfig/config compatible Rails >= 3.1, 4 and 5